# Create a Diagonal Matrix with specified number of rows and columns in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, apache-spark-mllib

I have an input `mllib` Block matrix named `matrix` like,

```
matrix : org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix =
0.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
2.0  0.0  2.0  4.0
1.0  2.0  0.0  3.0
2.0  4.0  3.0  0.0
```

As per my Scala code, diagonals will be `zero` for sure. I need the diagonals of the `matrix` to be 1. If I have a `diagonal matrix` with diagonal values as `1` like,

```
diagonalMatrix: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix =
1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

I can add those matrices, So the `diagonals` of `matrix` will be changed to 1.

```
matrix : org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix =
    1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
    2.0  1.0  2.0  4.0
    1.0  2.0  1.0  3.0
    2.0  4.0  3.0  1.0
```

We can create a `diagonal matrix` with specified number of `rows` and `columns` and `diagonals` as `1` based on the answer given below. But as the number of `rows` and `columns` were too big, I need an `optimized solution`. Or is there any better solution to make diagonals of `matrix` to `1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val nR = 5
val nC = 5

val seq = for {
  i <- 0 until nC
  j <- 0 until nR
  v = if (i == j) 1d else 0d
} yield v

val matrix = DenseMatrix(nR, nC, seq.toArray)
```

Comment: Yes. This works fine. But still even more optimized solution is welcomed. Because the size of my matrix is going to be very large.